# Can glusterfs volume be created out of directory instead of partition?

Tags: glusterfs

I want to create volume using glusterfs. Can glusterfs volume be created out of directory instead of partition ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that should work. I pretty much use it that way during development/testing:

`gluster volume create testvol replica 3 myhost:/home/ravi/bricks/brick{1..6} force`

Unless you want to use features like snapshot which require thinly provisioned lvms as partitions.

Might I also add that if you place multiple bricks of different distribute subvols on the same folder, things like `df` and quotas might not always work as intended.